# POST requests fail to execute on localhost using React

Tags: reactjs, post, localhost

In my React app, I use multiple GET and POST requests towards an API end-point on my server (https://www.example.com/api).

This works fine when I put the build on the server.
When developing on localhost however, I notice the POST requests fail to execute.

They connect to the same end-point on the actual server. I have a CORS extension on Chrome to deal with CORS-issues, and the GET requests work just fine.

The POST request shows a 200 status code in Chrome, but on the timings tab it says: `caution request is not finished yet`, and the response is blank.

So I dug a little deeper, and changed the end-point URL to `https://postman-echo.com/post`, which is basically a test API end-point for POST request. Result: this works just fine in localhost, and I get a response back from the end-point.

So I'm puzzled... what could it be that is causing POST requests to my server end-point to fail, while the GET requests do work.

I also tried this without React with jQuery, and it works perfectly fine in that case.

## TL;DR summary:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+--------+------------+--------+
|    Host     |       End-point       | Method | Framework  | Result |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| localhost   | example.com/api       | GET    | React      | Works  |
| localhost   | example.com/api       | POST   | React      | Fails  |
| localhost   | example.com/api       | POST   | jQuery     | Works  |
| localhost   | postman-echo.com/post | POST   | React      | Works  |
| example.com | example.com/api       | POST   | React      | Works  |
+-------------+-----------------------+--------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue on multiple browsers or Chrome only?

Comment: show your fetch function.

Comment: Chrome only. Firefox seems to work.